# PHP make Array from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, shopping-cart

i working on Authorize.net gateway i need to create below array for itemized bill

```
$sql= "select *  from shop where cusid = '1'";
 $sqlexc= mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$line_items = array();
while ($title = mysql_fetch_array($sqlexc)) {
    $line_items[] = ('Coupon',' $title[6]', '1', '0.99', 'Y');
}
```

how to create below kind of array

```
/*    $line_items = array(
    "Coupon1','description','2','10.99','Y'",
    "Coupon2','description','2','10.99','Y'",
    "Coupon3','description','2','10.99','Y'",);*/
```

Comment: You may want to re-read the array you want to output, don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: Your array doesn't make sense. What are your double quotes, single quotes and commas mean? Is this an array of strings? Or is this an array of objects that contain 4 properties?

Answer (score 0):

uh.. if you want it to be exactly the same...

```
$i=0;
$line_items = array();   
while ($title = mysql_fetch_array($sqlexc)) {
    $line_items[] = "Coupon" . ++$i . "', '" . $title[6] . "', '2', '10.99', 'Y'";
}
```

However I would use mysql_fetch_assoc over mysql_fetch_array (actually I would switch to PDO as mysql is deprecated)

Comment: how to add comma to the last records like  

    $line_items = array(
    "Coupon1','description','2','10.99','Y'",
    "Coupon2','description','2','10.99','Y'",
    "Coupon3','description','2','10.99','Y'",);

Comment: You don't need one.. That is purely optional. Look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php Look at "The comma after the last array element is optional and can be omitted."

Answer (score 0):

```
$line_items = array();
while ($title = mysql_fetch_array($sqlexc)) {
    $line_items[] = $title;
}
foreach ($line_items as $row){
    echo $row[0]." ".$row[1]." ".$row[2]." ".$row[3]."<br>";
}
```